StarterGUI won't fill screen
ROBLOX STUDIO:
I'm trying to make a full-screen menu for the player to buy things off but I'm finding that when I put a frame as a background then the GUI shuffles down to accommodate the built-in menu bar (leave game, chat, leaderboard), and I don't want this. See screenshot:
Roblox screenGUI doesn't fill screen
I made a full screen GUI that is supposed to appear over the top of the user's screen and show them an upgrades menu, but it is not filling the screen and a line of world is still visible above it, at the menu bar with the leave game, chat, leaderboard etc.
Again, see screenshot.

Please include a minimal reproducible example when you ask a question so we can better recreate your problem help you. For your case, edit in the code the creating the GUI you showed in your screenshot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Sorry! I'm quite new to Stack Overflow. I'll get some up when I next have time.

You should enabled IgnoreGuiInset inside the ScreenGui properties to make the gui ignore the default gui inset.
